# How do I define the type of a field starting with a @?

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I am trying to create a stream from some kakfa messages in json format like :

```
"beat": {
        "name": "xxxxxxx",
        "hostname": "xxxxxxxxxx",
        "version": "zzzzz"
    },
"log_instance": "forwarder-2",
"type": "prod",
"message": "{ ... json string.... }",
"@timestamp": "2020-06-14T23:31:33.925Z",
"input_type": "log",
"@version": "1"
}
```

I tried using

```
CREATE STREAM  S (
    beat STRUCT<
        name VARCHAR,
        hostname VARCHAR,
        version VARCHAR
    >,
    log_instance VARCHAR,
    type VARCHAR,
    message VARCHAR,   # for brevity - I also have this with a struct
    @timestamp VARCHAR,
    input_type VARCHAR,
    @version` VARCHAR )
WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='some_topic', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');
```

However I get an error :

```
Caused by: line 10:5: extraneous input '@' expecting ....
```

I tied quoting and preceeding underscore but no luck. I also tried creating an entry in the registry but I could not create legit avro this way.

PS. How do I "bind" a topic to a registry schema?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried back ticks ` instead of regular quotation marks?

Comment: yes - I meant to add I tried that also. Thanks.

Comment: hmm.. I tried again and it worked from ksql cli with `` but did not from the avro specification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on a recent enough version of ksqlDB then simply quoting the column names with invalid characters should work:

```sql
CREATE STREAM  S (
    beat STRUCT<
        name VARCHAR,
        hostname VARCHAR,
        version VARCHAR
    >,
    log_instance VARCHAR,
    type VARCHAR,
    message VARCHAR,   # for brevity - I also have this with a struct
    `@timestamp` VARCHAR,
    input_type VARCHAR,
    `@version` VARCHAR )
WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='some_topic', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');
```

If the above doesn't work, then it's likely you're on an old version of ksqlDB. Upgrading should fix this issue.

> PS. How do I "bind" a topic to a registry schema?

ksqlDB will auto-publish the JSON schema to the Schema Registry if you use the `JSON_SR` format, rather than just `JSON`.  The latter only supports *reading* the schema from the schema registry.

If you're more asking how you register a schema in the SR for an existing topic... then you're best off looking at the SR docs.  Note, ksqlDB only supports the `TopicNameStrategy` [naming strategy](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/index.html#sr-schemas-subject-name-strategy). The value schema has the subject `{topic-name}-value`, e.g. the following registers a JSON schema for the `test` topic's values.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json" --data '{"schema": "{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"Payment\",\"namespace\":\"io.confluent.examples.clients.basicavro\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"id\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"amount\",\"type\":\"double\"}]}"}' http://localhost:8081/subjects/test-value/versions
```

See the SR tutorial for more info: https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/schema_registry_tutorial.html

> I also tried creating an entry in the registry but I could not create legit avro this way.

Avro does not allow `@` in its field names. However, it looks like your data is in JSON format, which does allow `@`. See the curl example above on how to register a JSON schema.

Comment: Thank you! Most helpful.